# How is the Windows notification about a missing DLLs implemented?

Tags: windows, winapi

We've all seen "The code execution cannot proceed because xxxxxx.dll was not found." message box in Windows, that pops up when application launch fails due to a missing dependency.

And yet, I cannot figure out how it works: there seems to be no Windows API that allows to discover *which* DLL is missing after CreateProcess fails with a STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND error code...

Does anyone know how this is implemented?

Edit: And yeah, I'd like to obtain name of the missing DLL programmatically, in the process that calls CreateProcess().

Comment: Google "windows loader snaps" to get ahead.

Comment: CreateProcess not fail

Comment: Enabling loader snaps requires changes under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry tree, which needs admin privileges, so I doubt it's that.

Answer (score 1):

> there seems to be no Windows API that allows to discover which DLL is missing after CreateProcess fails with a STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND error code

Correct, there is no such API available.

> Does anyone know how is this implemented?

When an EXE is being loaded prior to starting the execution of its code, the OS's loader scans the EXE's PE header to discover the required DLLs, and then it attempts to load each of those DLLs.  If any of those DLLs fail to load, the loader is the one who is displaying the popup message, and it knows which DLL just failed, so it includes that DLL's name in the error message.  But that information is not passed down to the caller who originally asked for the EXE to run.

FYI, when using `CreateProcess()` to run an EXE, you can disable that popup error message by calling [`SetErrorMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode)/[`SetThreadErrorMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setthreaderrormode) beforehand, specifying the `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` flag:

> | Value | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS 0x0001 | The system does not display the critical-error-handler message box. Instead, the system sends the error to the calling process. Best practice is that all applications call the process-wide `SetErrorMode` function with a parameter of `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` at startup. This is to prevent error mode dialogs from hanging the application. |

Comment: SetErrorMode()/SetThreadErrorMode() set error mode for current process/thread. but error was not in current (which call CreateProcess and this api is ok - return true in concrete case) but in new process. need use `NtSetInformationProcess` with `ProcessDefaultHardErrorMode` and flag `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` is inverted compare kernel32 api. so create new process in suspended state, set error mode for it and resume

Comment: I am not sure this is the whole story: the loader would be executing in the context of the launched process, however the message window appears to be owned by "csrss" service process.  It seems that there's some communication going on.

Comment: @user1411900 obviously, I simplified the procedure. Operatimg Systems are complex beasts, there are a lot of things that go on behind the scenes.

Comment: @user1411900 - *however the message window appears to be owned by "csrss" service process* - loader call `ZwRaiseHardError` api - it do lpc call to csrss and csrss show MessageBox

Comment: Thanks @RbMm, this is the level of detail I was looking for.