# Getting error string from child process exit code

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a way, in Windows, to get the error string for when a child process fails to run due to, i.e., a missing DLL?

The child process is executed by `cmd.exe /c "<executable>"`

Doing the following

```
FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
               FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
               FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
               NULL,
               exit_code,
               MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
               (LPSTR)&buffer,
               0,
               NULL);
```

Does not work.

Comment: What exit code did the child process return? How are you using `FormatMessage`?

Comment: Have you tried using `GetLastError`? How are you executing the child process?

Comment: Code helps questions too many ways to count.

Comment: I edited the message with code

Comment: The more important code is where you are executing the process, the exit code is not generally useful, the program can set it to whatever it likes

Comment: What I'm trying to capture is Windows errors like "The code execution cannot proceed because <dll name> was not found...."

Comment: Executing via `cmd` wont help, is there a reason you don't run the executable directly?

Comment: Because the requirement is that users can execute arbitrary commands from the file they're read from.

Comment: what is exit code ? faster it from ntdll. need use FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE and GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll")

Comment: FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE just gives the format string. We also want to know what DLL is missing.

Comment: Use [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)  _...Note that the function returns before the process has finished initialization. If a __required DLL__ cannot be located or fails to initialize, the process is terminated. To get the termination status of a process, call [GetExitCodeProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess)..."_

Comment: You can read [the earlier Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72924161/15511041) which has an explanation.